# Can't run react native expo project on android emulator

Tags: react-native, expo

After `npm start` everything works fine. Now I am trying to open the emulator by pressing `a` and that error shows:
`Couldn't start project on Android:`. 
This is my `~/.bashrc` file ( using Ubuntu )

```
export ANDOIRD_SDK=/home/toma/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I have this emulator opened from android studio.
[image]

Emulator settings:
[image]

Comment: you need to have the Android emulator opened, then you can open the project on it. Let me know if that works!

Comment: The android studio emulator ?

Comment: Yes, or any other android device needs to be connected with debugging mode turned on. For now you can try with emulator

Comment: Edit my question to show what I`ve opened :)

Comment: Still the same error occur. Can i check for error log somewhere ?

Comment: try running ```adb devices``` in terminal, if it shows your emulator as online then it is up for running the app

Comment: `emulator-5554 unauthorized` . This is what I get. Guess it is detectable but is that unauthorized normal ?

Comment: No it means that the emulator is not having debugging mode on. this video might help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoBgEn04rLw.  After turning debugging mode on try to run this command. if the emulator shows online/device then it will be able to run the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step: 1
Open emulator from AVD manager from Android Studio. Check if the emulator has debugging mode on

Step: 2
run `npm start`

Step 3:
press `a`

It should start the app in emulator.

Comment: Still the same error. Successfully enabled usb debugging. After running adb devices I can see that this line are shown: `List of devices attached
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
* daemon started successfully
emulator-5556 unauthorized
`. And the vysor connection is broken,and the emulator again comes the unauthorized.

Comment: Try running ```adb kill-server ``` and then ```adb start-server``` commands in terminal, you will have to close emulator befor running the command and then re run the emulator after second command. also wipe data using avd manager https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioM5B.png before re running the emulator

Comment: Nope. Again this. Editing the question with my export paths in the `~/.bashrc` file. I think I maybe did something wrong there.

Comment: I want to look at it your emulator configuration can you post screenshot of it?

Comment: Your emulator must have the system image with google apis, you can change it using avd manager please refer to this screenshot. https://prnt.sc/rwq98e | https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgrlx.png

Comment: Yes, the images helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled the Expo App in the emulator, then

`npm start`